# add CDATA to xml node

Tags: php, xml

This php code works correctly, but how do I add CDATA to content node?

```
 <?php
 $xml = new DomDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
 $xml->load('xmldata.xml');

 $title    = $_POST['title'];
 $avtor    = $_POST['avtor'];
 $date     = $_POST['date'];
 $category = $_POST['category'];
 $content  = $_POST['content'];

$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("root")->item(0);

   $postingTag = $xml->createElement("posting");

     $titleTag    = $xml->createElement("title",    $title);
     $avtorTag    = $xml->createElement("avtor",    $avtor);
     $dateTag     = $xml->createElement("date",     $date);
     $categoryTag = $xml->createElement("category", $category);
     $contentTag  = $xml->createElement("content",  $content);

     $postingTag->appendChild($titleTag);
     $postingTag->appendChild($avtorTag);
     $postingTag->appendChild($dateTag);
     $postingTag->appendChild($categoryTag);
     $postingTag->appendChild($contentTag);

   $rootTag->appendChild($postingTag);

$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->save('xmldata.xml');
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.createcdatasection.php ?

Comment: CDATA or a CDATA  section?

Answer (score 12):

DOM separates node create and append. You create the node using a method of the document and append it using methods of the parent node.

Here is an example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$root = $document->appendChild(
  $document->createElement('element-name')
);
$root->appendChild(
  $document->createCDATASection('one')
);
$root->appendChild(
  $document->createComment('two')
);
$root->appendChild(
  $document->createTextNode('three')
);

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element-name><![CDATA[one]]><!--two-->three</element-name>
```

`DOMNode::appendChild()` and similar methods return the appended node, so you can combine them with the `DOMDocument::create*()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

CDATA or a CDATA  section?

```
$cdata = 'This is my character data!';
```

For the first use the second parameter of `createElement('tagname', 'cdata')` - hey you already do it here:

```
$contentTag  = $xml->createElement("content",  $content);
                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

for the second `createCDATASection()` and append it as child to the created element:

```
$contentTag  = $xml->createElement("content",  $content);
$contentTag->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($cdata);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or something like this should work

```
  $name          = $dom->createElement('name');
  $cdataname     = $dom->createCDATASection('Your CDATA text');

  $name->appendChild($cdataname);

  // whatever node you have here
  $node->appendChild($name);
```

It will produce this:

```
  <product>
   <name>
     <![CDATA[Your CDATA text]]>
   </name>
  </product>
```